# Can I summon two dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am able to summon the dragon from Soul Cairn (Durnehviir), and use the shout, 'Call Dragon' (Odahviing). Can I summon two dragons at the same time or still one?

Comment: I am assuming you are including the dragon Odahviing with the Call Dragon shout?

Comment: Precisely. Can you summon them both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...Yes and no.

Using the Call Dragon shout, you can summon Odahviing, but the shout to Summon Durnehviir will become unusable until the cooldown on the Call Dragon shout is complete (also the same in reverse).

So *yes*, you can have both in your little squad at the same time, *but* you can't summon both *at the same time*.

Comment: Of course, if you're playing on PC you can use console commands and/or mods to force the cooldown to be lower (or nonexistent) thereby allowing the use of both shouts. Results while using the console can have unintended consequences. Use at your own risk. Always make a backup save first.